# A nonempty subset $H$ of a finite group $G$ is a subgroup if and only if $H$ is closed

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> I need to prove **proposition 1**, and this is what I have.

**Definition 1:** *If there exists a nonzero integer such that $a^m=e$, then the **order** of the element $'a'$ is defined to be the least positive integer $'n'$ such that $a^n=e$*

*If there does not exists a nonzero integer $m$ such that $a^m=e$, then the order is infinity*

**Definition 2:** *A subset $H$ of a group $G$ is a **subgroup** if*

1. $e\in H$
2. if $x,y\in H$, then $xy\in H$.
3. if $x\in H$, then $x^{-1}\in H$

**Proposition 1:** *A noneempty subset $H$ of a finite goup $G$ is a subgroup if and only if $H$ is closed*

*proof*:
$\Rightarrow )$ Let H be a noneempty set of a finite grout $G$, then we know by **definition 2(2)** that $H$ is closed under group multiplication.

$\Leftarrow $): $H$ is finite therefore if $a\in H$, then $\text{ord}(a)=n$. Thus $e=a^n\in H$. We have shown that $e\in H$. If we can show that for every $h\in H$ that $h^{-1}\in H$, then we can conclude that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. So let $h\in H$, then we know that there exists a element $k\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $h^k=e$. But then $h^{k-1}=h^{-1}$ and $h^{k-1} h=h h^{k-1}=e$. So $h^{-1}\in H$.

Therefore $H$ is a subgroup of $G$

> **My question is:**
>
> - Is this a correct proof, because I don't know if $\text{ord}(a)=n$ when $H$ is finite?

Comment: You don't need the part about $n$, which anyway you didn't specify (unless you meant it is $\operatorname{ord}(a)$ by definition). The existence of $k>0$ with $h^k=e$ evoked a bit further on suffices. And that existence is clear, the infinitely many values $h^i$ for $i\in\Bbb N$ cannot all be different, and once $h^i=h^j$ with $i>j$ you can take $k=i-j$.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now. This is much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a consequence of Lagrange's Theorem: The size of a subgroup is a divisor of the size of a subgroup.

Comment: Actually, some texts (e.g. Fraleigh) pose this problem long before Lagrange's Theorem; the result falls out from the definition of a group, and the premises. One doesn't need Lagrange at all to prove the above. In some senses, one could argue that Lagrange's Theorem follows...